# Thread returning calculation

Tags: c, multithreading

I am trying to multiply matrices by using threads. I am not able to return a value from a thread to display in another function.

Example code of the main and first thread below.

```
void MC0(int *);
void Answer(int, int);
int c0=0, c1=0;

void MC0(int * c0){
    c0 = arrayCopy[1]*arrayCopy[9];     //arrayCopy is a copy of the input from the main "argv"
    pthread_exit(0);
}

void Answer(int c0, int c1){
    printf("c0: %d c1: %d", c0, c1);
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[]){

    pthread_create(&myThread1, NULL, (void *) MC0, (void *) &c0);
    sleep(1);
    pthread_create(&myThread2, NULL, (void *) MC1, (void *) &c1);
    sleep(1);

    pthread_join(myThread1, NULL);
    sleep(1);
    pthread_join(myThread2, NULL);
    sleep(1);

    Answer(c0, c1);

    exit(0);
}
```

I probably have to do something with `pthread_mutex_lock` but I'm not sure how to do that. Pretty much I am trying to return `c0` from the `MC0` function to be able to display using `printf` in the `Answer(int, int)` function.

Comment: Hint: What is the second parameter of `pthread_join()` used for? By the way your program would make the compiler cry with `-Wshadow` declare the global variables inside `main()`.

Comment: If you're new to C, a multithread application is probably not where you should start.

Comment: @Degustaf We did a sequential program and now he wants us to turn that into a multithreaded. I've always coded in Java and only a few times in C so this is a little confusing to me. I do get it a little but not fully enough to code this  comfortably. @iharob I pass `(void *) &c0`? is that what I'm suppose to do in that second parameter?

Comment: What do you think the return value of the thread's start function is for?  And speaking of that, the signature of your start function is wrong: it should return `void *`.  If the signature were right then you would not need a cast.

Answer (score 1):

Since each thread is writing to a global variable, you don't need to do anything further. After the main thread has executed `pthread_join(myThread1, NULL)`, thread 1 has executed its assignment at the address `&c0`, so by the time the `Answer` function is executed, `c0` contains the result from thread 1.

When breaking your problem down into threads, take care that you don't have two threads writing to the same location, or a thread reading where another thread may write. That's the easiest way to avoid race conditions.

If you want to change away from using a global variable to pass the result, you can choose to return a value from the function that contains the thread's code. The function must return a value of type `void *`; in fact, this is necessary whether you use the value or not, so your program is incorrect (though it's likely to work on many machines). The second argument to `pthread_join`, if non-null, is a pointer to a location where that `void*` value will be written. Note that the `void*` value needs to remain valid after the thread exits: it can be a pointer to a global variable, or a pointer to heap memory (memory allocated by `malloc`), but it cannot be a pointer into the terminating thread's stack. Here's an example where the function returns a block of memory allocated on the heap.

```
void *MC0(void *ignored) {
    int *row = malloc(…);
    …
    return row;
}
int main() {
    …
    pthread_t thread1;
    pthread_create(&thread1, NULL, MC0, NULL);
    …
    void *row1;
    pthread_join(thread1, &row1);
    …
    free(row1);
}
```